# How to dynamically generate variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to dynamically generate variables `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` and assign `bar` to them using the following code:

```
for (var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    myapp.set({ foo+i: "bar" })
}
```

I tried using `eval` on `foo` by it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an array? Accessing data will be easier.

Comment: Can you post the code that you used when you tried using `eval` on `foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    var myObj = {};
    myObj['foo' + i] = 'bar';

    myapp.set(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with square brackets.  If you want the variables to be in the global scope, then use `window['foo'+i]`.

Eg:

```
for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    window['foo'+i] = 'bar';
    // OR, if you want them in 'myApp' scope:
    myApp['foo'+i] = 'bar';
}
```

Comment: Why put variables in the global scope? Smells like bad architecture...

Comment: It's just an example, showing a pattern you can apply to whatever scope you want.  I didn't recommend OP use the global scope any more than any answer recommends you use 'foo' as a variable name.

Comment: Just saying we probably shouldn't use a global scope example. A lot of people are new to programming, and this could lead to confusion. Most new programmers understand that foo is a generic name, while a lot of people don't understand what global scope is. I guess I could have posed a better comment, but I just wanted people to think twice before copying and pasting

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/TASfG/

```
var myApp = {};

for (var i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    myApp['foo'+i] = "bar";
}

console.log(myApp);
```